# C# HTML get all checkboxes and press them randomly

Tags: c#, html, random, checkbox, com

I am desperate for help. I have tried to get all checkboxes from a website and press them randomly.
The random function should choose one of the 3 following checkboxes in the list of all checkboxes. Something like this : it chooses randomly just one checkbox from checkbox 1 to checkbox 4. Then it chooses another checkbox randomly from checkbox 4 to checkbox 7.

I already have problems getting all the checkboxes and check like 1 of them.

This is the HTML code for 1 checkbox

```
<input id="m_embeddedProfileControl_m_questionSheet_ctl02_1012343_3056092_0"         type="checkbox" name="m_embeddedProfileControl$m_questionSheet$ctl02$ctl00$1012343_3056092"  onclick="javascript:return   ChangeCheckBoxAnswerValue(C1012343_3056092,3056092,'',1012343,true);">
```

And this is my try so far in visual studio 2013

```
HtmlElementCollection test = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement blub in test)
{
    if (blub.GetAttribute("type").Equals("checkbox"))
    {
        blub.InvokeMember("onclick");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try using some jquery to do the selection process.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
private void CheckOneRandomly(HtmlElement[] chks)
{
  chks[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Random()*chks.length)-1].InvokeMember("onclick");
}
```